# Determining if input data is "balanced"

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, file-io

I have been creating a program that checks if an input file (passed in using file redirection) has all matching parentheses, brackets, and/or braces. (Ex: [][]{}() is "balanced", while [[}] is "not balanced").

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;



int main() {
    
    stack<char> paren;
    string contents;
    
    while(cin >> contents) {
        for(auto &i : contents) {
            if(contents[i] == '(' || contents[i] == '{' || contents[i] == '[') {
                paren.push(contents[i]);
            }
            if(contents[i] == ')' || contents[i] == '}' || contents[i] == ']') {
                if(paren.top() == '(' || paren.top() == '{' || paren.top() == '[') {
                    paren.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    if(paren.empty() == true) {
        cout << "Balanced" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Not Balanced" << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am running into two problems I need help with:

(1) The terminal (I am using a Mac for reference) tells me about implicit conversion changes when I am using the [] operator on the strings to locate each individual character to compare it. Is there some sort of cast or other way to index the string so that this error does not show up? Or would my code work if I read in the data as characters?

(2) The logic of my program only works for some of the test cases. What am I missing in my algorithm to make this work for all types of input?

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: `for(auto &i : contents)` -- Ask yourself this:  What type of variable is `i`?  Is it an index, i.e. `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.?  Print out the value of `i` in that loop, and that would give you a hint as to the issue.

Comment: Sometimes `auto` is the devil.

Comment: Is `[(])` balanced?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh I see now. That was a dumb mistake by me! Thank you

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, that would be considered balanced

Comment: @Marshal -- If that is considered balanced, you don't need a stack for this problem.  A simple counter that increments on an opening brace, and decrements on a closing brace is all you need, ensuring that the counter never goes negative, and ends up at 0 when going through the string.   A stack would be used if you truly wanted to match each type of opening / closing brace and to make sure the braces are balanced.

Comment: Is `}{` Balanced? That would affect @PaulSanders Answer.

Comment: @Alan Good question!

Comment: I dunno if it is balanced, but `}{` does look like a Pink Floyd album cover.

Comment: Since you only ever push `'('`, `'{'`, and `'['` into `paren`, you don't need to check if it's one of those three values when popping it back out. (You may need to check whether `paren` is empty, which you currently don't.)

Comment: @PaulSanders yes that would be considered balanced. Great question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need a stack for this - you can just keep track of the number of open and close brackets that you see as you work your way through the input string.

So, on the assumption that different types of bracket must be differentiated, you could do something like this (I also fixed your ranged `for` loop):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string contents;
    
    while (std::cin >> contents)
    {
        int paren_count = 0, brace_count = 0, bracket_count = 0;

        for (auto c : contents)
        {
            if (c == '(')
                ++paren_count;
            if (c == '{')
                ++brace_count;
            if (c == '[')
                ++bracket_count;

            if (c == ')')
                --paren_count;
            if (c == '}')
                --brace_count;
            if (c == ']')
                --bracket_count;
        }

        if (paren_count || brace_count || bracket_count)
            std::cout << "Not Balanced\n";
        else        
            std::cout << "Balanced\n";
    }
}
```

Sample input: `()`
Output: `Balanced`

Comment: Oh I see. This makes a lot more sense, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

(1) The issue here is a confusion between regular `for` loops and enhanced `for` loops. When you write `for(auto &i : contents)`, the correct way to access the data is simply `if(i == '(' ||`...
Writing `if(contents[i] == '(' ||` attempts to cast `i`, declared as a `char&` (as deduced from `value_type` member in `std::string`) to an `int` to satisfy `operator[](int)` on the `std::string`.

(2) Redirecting a file to `stdin` will not cause `std::cin` to enter an error state until the file has finished reading.